# how to use dynamic where experssion in linq query in C#?

Tags: sql, linq, lambda

```
        var query = from c in countryStates
                    where (c.CountryStateID.ToString().Contains(_RestrictCountryStateID))
                    orderby c.CountryStateDesc
                    select c;
```

in this code _RestrictCountryStateID is a string that contains CountrySateIDs 
and i dont know for every query i have how many CountrySateIDs  in _RestrictCountryStateID .

how can write where for this scenario?

Comment: this query did not work.

Answer (score 0):

make `_RestrictCountryStateID` a comma seperated string. Then following will work:

```
var ids = _RestrictCountryStateID.Split(',');
var query = from c in countryStates where ids.Contains(c.CountryStateID)
                    orderby c.CountryStateDesc
                    select c;
```